# How to use special characters \n in URL

Tags: swift, url, post, swift3

I have POST request:

```
init (url: String,arg: String) {
    self.responseString = nil
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = arg
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 
            print("error=\(error)")
            self.responseString = nil
            return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           //
            self.responseString = nil
        } else {
        self.responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    }
```

When arg have a character \n, half arg text is lost. How fix this problem?

Comment: I do not see how a newline makes sense within an URL string, but in general you can percentage-escape url strings: `let ecaped = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strUrl = strUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

let url = URL.init(string: strUrl)

let requestURL = URLRequest(url: url!)
```

- You need to add addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) method to allow URL Query.